# How to configure Postfix to use Gmail SMTP on Ubuntu 16.04 / 17.10

Tags: postfix

I installed the Postfix mail transfer agent using the command `sudo apt install mailutils`.

I am using the following command in my terminal.

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" marksman283@gmail.com
```

It runs fine but I want to use my gmail account. How can I do this?

Note that my Ubuntu version is 18.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.configure Postfix**

Edit the Postfix configuration file.

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Find the following line relayhost = about 6 lines up from the bottom of the file and delete it.

*Add the following to the end of the file.*

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Save file and exit. (Press CTRL + X, press Y and then press ENTER)

**2. Create Password and DB Files**

Create the sasl_passwd file which will store our credentials.

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Insert the following:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 username@gmail.com:password
```

Save file and exit. (Press CTRL + X, press Y and then press ENTER)

Create a hash database file for Postfix with the postmap command.

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

There should now be a file called sasl_passwd.db in the /etc/postfix/ directory.

For added security, we will only allow root user to read and write to sasl_passwd and sasl_passwd.db

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
sudo chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

**3.Send a Test Mail**

We’ll now send a test email message. Make sure to replace test@example.com with your own email address.

```
echo "Test Email message body" | mail -s "Email test subject" test@example.com
```