# How can I configure postfix to send emails via gmail (2FA problems)?

Tags: email, postfix, mdadm, gmail, smart

I have a new Ubuntu 18.04 system and want to have `mdadm`, `smartd`, et al. to send warning emails through my gmail account. I have followed the guides in [How can I configure Postfix to send all email through my Gmail account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228938/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-send-all-email-through-my-gmail-account) and [How to configure Postfix to use Gmail SMTP on Ubuntu 16.04 / 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059245/how-to-configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10), but I keep getting authentication failures. I have two-factor authentication (2FA) set up with my gmail account. Could this be a factor?

Comment: Yes that the issue please check google as they should an option to use special app credentials where 2FA is impossible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As George suggested, 2FA was indeed a factor. I wrote down the full procedure below that solved my problems:

## Install packages

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

- Select `Internet host`.
- Enter a hostname (does not have to be known to the internet), e.g.,  `trillian.at.home`.

## Get app password from google

Google allows you to set up 'apps' that have their own password. This technique works with mail relays, too.

- Visit your app passwords page (https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords).
- Log in using your two-factor authentication method.
- Select app: `Mail` and device: `Other`.
- Give your 'app' a name, e.g., `mail relay from <hostname>`.
- Press `Generate`.
- Write down the 'app' password (16 characters, no spaces).

## Store the app password

Open/create a password file:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd
```

Put the following text in the file:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 USERNAME@gmail.com:APP-PASSWORD
```

where USERNAME is your gmail username and APP-PASSWORD is the 16-digit app password.

Create a hash file:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd
```

Ensure that only root can read/write the password files:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd.db
sudo chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd.db
```

## Create a certificate file

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

## Configure postfix

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Remove the `relayhost` line and ensure that the following lines are in the file.

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/relay_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

## Test

Run

```
echo "Test email" | mail -s "Test" you@gmail.com
```

Hopefully your mail has appeared at gmail. Otherwise, use `mailq` and `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` for debugging.

## Set up mdadm and smartd

If the test email arrived, you can now set up `mdadm` and `smartd`. For `mdadm`, I use the line

```
MAILADDR MY-GMAIL-USERNAME+mdadm-trillian@gmail.com
```

in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` to enable mail filtering in my gmail inbox. Similarly, I use the text

```
-m MY-GMAIL-USERNAME+smartd-trillian@gmail.com
```

in my `DEVICESCAN` line in `/etc/smartd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) to get it working as 2FA affects these apps but here is a summary:

1. Visit your App passwords page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
2. At the bottom, click Select app and choose the app you’re using.
3. Click Select device and choose the device you’re using.
4. Select Generate.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar) on your device.
6. Select Done.

Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again. However, you will see a list of apps and devices you’ve created App passwords for.

READ MORE:

https://duo.com/blog/bypassing-googles-two-factor-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get email working as per the above instructions on Ubuntu 22.04 but with the following caveat:

- I was not able to create the certificate file (/etc/ssl/certs/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem  does not exist) and
- I did not add "smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem" to "/e/etc/postfix/main.cftc/postfix/main.cf"